# Como criar uma aplicação Ruby On Rails (Não apenas uma API) e disponibilizar algumas rotas como API

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema comum com ROR e o mesmo possui uma estrutura não apenas de uma API, pois tem suas views e tudo mais.

A questão é que eu vou também construir uma API para servi-la para um app mobile e quando vou pesquisar sobre o assunto só encontro pessoas explicando como construir uma aplicação apenas como api através do parâmetro:

```
rails new [my-app] --api
```

Porém dessa forma a aplicação precisa de configurações diferentes e é bem mais enxuta do que a aplicação normal. Gostaria de utilizar a seguinte abordagem, seguir uma aplicação normal e criar um grupo de rotas para servir a API, com autenticação e tudo mais.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode executar o `rails new` sem a flag `--api`. Assim, você mantém o Action View e tudo mais.

Então, você terá uma camada de API e uma camada de Asset Pipeline, o padrão do Rails. Para criar essa camada de API, crie uma pasta em `app/controllers/api` e coloque seus controllers da API lá. Também crie um `app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb`, que vai ser a base de todos os controllers da API.

```
# app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb
class API::BaseController < ActionController::API
end
```

Veja que ele herda de `ActionController::API`, o mesmo que herdaria se você criasse a aplicação com a flag `--api`, a diferença é que você mantém o `ApplicationController`.

Agora, vamos criar um controller.

```
# app/controllers/api/greetings_controller.rb
class API::GreetingsController < API::BaseController
  def index
    render json: { message: 'Hello World!' }, status: :ok
  end
end
```

E as rotas:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :greetings, only: :index
  end
end
```

E pronto! Você tem o Asset Pipeline funcionando junto com uma API, escopada em `API::`.

Comment: Olá meu amigo, obrigado, vou testar isso

Comment: Só um adendo, quando eu coloque por exemplo API::GreetingsController houve um erro informando que não existia esse método, eu tive que substituir para Api::GreetingsController

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um `namespace` no seu `routes.rb` e chama-lo de `api` por exemplo:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :articles
end
```

Que vai gerar a seguinte tabela de rotas:

```
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
|   HTTP    |           Path           |       Controller       |         Named Helper         |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
| GET       | /api/articles          | api/articles#index   | api_articles_path          |
| GET       | /api/articles/new      | api/articles#new     | new_api_article_path       |
| POST      | /api/articles          | api/articles#create  | api_articles_path          |
| GET       | /api/articles/:id      | api/articles#show    | api_article_path(:id)      |
| GET       | /api/articles/:id/edit | api/articles#edit    | edit_api_article_path(:id) |
| PATCH/PUT | /api/articles/:id      | api/articles#update  | api_article_path(:id)      |
| DELETE    | /api/articles/:id      | api/articles#destroy | api_article_path(:id)      |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
```

É importante ressaltar que após fazer isso o seu controller tera que estar localizado no `controllers/api/`.

Você pode ler mais sobre isso [aqui](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, vou testar isso